# list navigation in view (Actionbar, Actionbarsherlock)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm looking for a way to use a list navigation like the one in the actionbar inside a view (e.g. `LinearLayout`)

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "the actionbar inside a view"? The action bar is outside of your activity's layout, not inside one of your `View`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list navigation is par of the Actionbar, so if you want to use something similar you will need to implement this on your own. You can use a spinner and customize its style to meet your need.

Comment: The Spinner widget is exactly what the ActionBar uses internally.

Comment: Thanks for the hint into the right direction. The IcsSpinner of ActionbarSherlock was exactly that what I was looking for.